# IE8 crashes on downloading PNGs

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, png

Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) is simply refusing to download a PNG image - it just crashes.

First, I thought it was the file size, so I saved it as a JPEG, which worked but then IE hung on the rest of the PNG images on the page. Does anyone have any solutions to this problem (or something like it), or could tell me *why* it's not working?

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox...

Edit: Here's the site URL: [www.easymanager.co.uk](http://www.easymanager.co.uk)

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? What happens?

Comment: IE doesn't respond anymore after I tried to open this site.

Comment: [Validating your site](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easymanager.co.uk%2F&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0) reports enough errors that ought to be a good starting point. IE might also require the `<DOCTYPE` piece to be the very first few bytes, not after a few newlines. None of those errors look like they should kill a browser; I suggest [reporting the bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/ie/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with the PNGs, IE is hanging because of two lines in the pages.css files. If you remove them the site is fine. I guess even IE doesn't like MS proprietary web stuff.

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cc000000,endColorstr=#cc0000 00);
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cc000000, endColorstr=#cc000000)";

Comment: Thanks CreeDorofl. It was indeed those lines - I removed them last night and it works fine now. What I don't get is the fact that they're Micro$oft's own commands. Why do they crash their own (rubbish) browser?

Comment: I dunno, but if that filter does what I think it does... draw a gradient across an area... you (or whoever runs the site) can just do that with a tiny repeated photoshop gif usually. Sites break when the designers get too cute :)

Comment: "too cute" ha ha. The filter does indeed draw a gradient, however I was just looking for solid colour transparency. I found the gradient hack a while back and it worked fine for a while, but then decided to die. I'm using LESS so I've come up with a little mask line to pretend to be transparent :-)